# Django: trying to link to one model inside of other models ListView

Tags: django, listview

I would like to get the Restaurant Id from the Restaurant model and use it for the href in the Lunchmenu listview. Don´t really know how to move forward from here. I have tried a for loop of the "restaurants_list" in the template but did not really understand how to get only one Id from the list.

Is there any way to do this in the template?
Should I change the View somehow?

Models:

```
 class LunchMenu(models.Model):
            restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

 class Restaurant(models.Model):
            manager = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Listview:

```
class LunchMenuListView(ListView):
    template_name = "lunchmenus/lunchmenu_home.html"
    model = LunchMenu

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LunchMenuListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["restaurants_list"] = Restaurant.objects.all()
        return context
```

Template:

```
<div class="row">
          {% for lunchmenu in lunchmenu_list %}
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                  <div class="card h-100">
                                <a href="/restaurants/{{restaurant.id}}"><img class="card-img-top" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt=""></a>
                    <div class="card-body">
                                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a href="#">{{lunchmenu.restaurant}}</a>
                    </h4>
                                <p class="card-text">{{lunchmenu.description  | safe}}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use `restaurant` field of the `lunchmenu` item like this:

```
<a href="/restaurants/{{ lunchmenu.restaurant.id }}">
```

Note that using hardcoded urls in this manner is not a best practice approach, you should use Django's built-in [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) template tag and use a named route which will give you a more robust solution with respect to the eventual changes in your urls scheme:

```
<a href="{% url 'restaurants:restaurant-detail' id=lunchmenu.restaurant.id %}">
```

(assuming that you have a `restaurants:restaurant-detail` route defined in your `urls.py` which takes `restaurant.id` as a parameter)